# jQuery (window).load after the page loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Will jQuery run the function passed in `$(window).load(callback)`, when this listener added after the `window.load` event?

Comment: Test it out :-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it won't: http://jsfiddle.net/WouterJ/zMEZA/

But a `$(window).ready` event will: http://jsfiddle.net/WouterJ/zMEZA/1/

Answer (score 9):

No, `$(window).load(function(){})` is only called if it's bound before the event.

On the flip side, `$(document).ready(function(){})` (and its shorthand `$(function(){})`) *will* be triggered (immediately) if they are bound after the event.

Comment: Both `$(window).load()` and `$(window).trigger('load');` trigger the event. It does not clear the queue though; `$().ready` is a better solution.